# MYSQL order NULL between two particular records and data

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to set the default order used by MYSQL to be NULL in a specific record.

**my columns:**

- `id` : id
- `state` : 'downloading','error','finish','fail'
- `try` :  number of try for download file.

**order in result:**

- downloading
- error : if try between 0 to 20
- NULL
- error : try lager than 20
- fail

**my table:**

```
id       state          try
----------------------------
1        NULL            0
2        error           25
3        downloading     1
4        NULL            0
5        finish          2
6        error           3
7        NULL            0
8        downloading     5
9        fail            51
10       error           3
11       error           21
12       error           8
13       finish          10
14       downloading     6
15       error           17
```

result after run query:

```
id       state         try
-------------------------------
3        downloading     1
8        downloading     5
14       downloading     6
10       error           3
12       error           8
15       error           17
6        error           3
1        NULL            0
4        NULL            0
7        NULL            0
11       error           21
2        error           25
9        fail            51
```

this my query not work:

```
 SELECT * FROM `report_table`
            WHERE state IN ('downloading', 'error','fail')
                OR state IS NULL
            ORDER BY
                CASE
                    WHEN state = 'downloading' THEN 1
                    WHEN state IS NULL THEN 2
                    WHEN state = 'error' THEN 3
                    WHEN state = 'fail' THEN 4
                    ELSE 6
                END , state ASC , try ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `report_table`
WHERE state IN ('downloading', 'error','fail') OR state IS NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN state = 'downloading' THEN 1
         WHEN state = 'error' AND try<=20 THEN 2
         WHEN state IS NULL THEN 3
         WHEN state = 'error' AND try>20 THEN 4
         WHEN state = 'fail' THEN 5
         ELSE 6
     END , state ASC , try ASC
```

Result:

```
id  state       try
3   downloading 1
8   downloading 5
14  downloading 6
6   error       3
10  error       3
12  error       8
15  error       17
7   (null)      0
4   (null)      0
1   (null)      0
11  error       21
2   error       25
9   fail        51
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6bdb/2).

Answer (score 0):

You just need the right `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN state = 'downloading' THEN 1
               WHEN state = 'error' and try between 0 and 20
               WHEN state IS NULL THEN 3
               WHEN state = 'error' THEN 4
               WHEN state = 'fail' THEN 5
               ELSE 6
          END), state ASC , try ASC
```

If you have no other values for `state`, then the `state ASC` is not needed in the `order by`.